# Finding probability of edges in a graph

Tags: graph, probability-theory

I have a random graph G(n, p) with n = 5000 vertices and an edge probability of p = 0.004.
I wonder what would be the expected number of edges in the graph but I have not much knowledge in probability-theory.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you so much!

**EDIT:**
If pE is the number of possible edges in the Graph, wouldn't I have to calculate 0.004 * pE to get the expected number of edges in the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ask yourself the maximum number of possible edges in the graph. This is when every vertex is connected to every single other vertex (nC2 = n * (n-1)/2), assuming this is an undirected graph without self-loops).

If each possible edge has a likelihood of 0.004, and the # of possible edges is n(n-1)/2, then the expected number of edges will be 0.004*(n(n-1)/2).

Comment: ah no i don't understand :-D...why is it divided by two ? Don't I have n-1 possibilitys to create edges from one vertex to others?

Comment: If i calculate it your way I would have about 12 million edges as maximum. So if the probability is 0.004 that there is one edge, shouldn't it be 0.004 * 12 mio?

Comment: The number of possible combinations of `r` items from a pool of `n` total items is `n!/((n-r)!*r!)`. Because an edge is a combination of 2 vertices from a pool of n vertices, the number of these is `n!/((n-2)!*2) = n*(n-1)*(n-2)!/((n-2)!*2) = n*(n-1)/2`... the (n-2)! cancels out.

As for your question about 0.004 * pE being the # of expected edges... You are right. My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

The number of expected vertices depend on the number of nodes and the edge probability as in E = p(n(n-1)/2).

The total number of possible edges in your graph is n(n-1) if any i is allowed to be linked to any j as both i->j and j->i. I am your friend, you are mine. If the graph is undirected (and an edge only means that we are friends) the total number of edges drop by half: n(n-1)/2 since i->j and j->i are the same.

The multiplication with p gives the expected number of edges, since every possible edge has become real or not depending on the probability. p=1 gives n(n-1)/2 edges since every possible edge actually happened. For graphs with p<1, the actual edge count might (obviously) differ from time to time if you were to actually generate a random graph using the p and n of your choice. Expected edge count will however be the most common observed edge count if you were to generate an infinite number of random graphs. NetLogo is a very pedagogical tool if you want to generate random graphs and get a feel for how network measurements arise from random graphs of different structures.